# tinymce editor - Add Text after editor is loaded

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor

I am trying add some text in a tinymce editor after it is loaded but it seems not to work

```
  tinymce.on('addeditor', function(e) {
    var editor = e.editor;
    editor.on('init', function(e) {
      editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'content');
    });
  }, true);
```

When I test the code in the console, I get this result:
Dispatcher {fire: ƒ, on: ƒ, off: ƒ, once: ƒ, has: ƒ}

Comment: the problem is that I do not have control of this editor. It is part of a software. The initialization is done by them, not me.

Answer (score 0):

This TinyMCE Fiddle shows how to load content via the editor's APIs:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/qigaab

Comment: Thanks Michael. It is helpful in general but the problem here is that I do not have control of this editor. It is part of a software. The initialization is done by them, not me. I can only add the text once everything is loaded.